# Lisp: decode-universal-time is void

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm editing orgmode, a time-management mode for emacs. I'm adding some new time functions.
In my addition i need to determine the day of the week for a given date. I use the following code:

```
(defun org-day-of-week (day month year)
(nth-value 6 (decode-universal-time (encode-universal-time 0 0 0 day month year 0) 0)))
```

Executing this code gives me the error:

nth-value: Symbol's function definition is void: decode-universal-time

I'm new to lisp, and can't find any info related to this error. I presume some libraries aren't loaded or available.
Can anyone please shed a light on this?

Regards,
Erwin Vrolijk
Snow.nl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially `decode-universal-time` is a Common Lisp function. These are not necessarily available in emacs-lisp. Some quick checking in a local emacs indicates that this is the fact.

Something close to your original implementation would be:

```
(defun org-day-of-week (year month day)
   (nth 6 
        (decode-time 
           (date-to-time 
             (format "%d-%02d-%02dT00:00:00" year month day)))))
```

You should be able to use `decode-time` instead (maybe in conjuction with `date-to-time`):

> decode-time is a built-in function in `C source code'.
> (decode-time &optional specified-time)
>
> Decode a time value as (SEC MINUTE HOUR DAY MONTH YEAR DOW DST ZONE).
> The optional specified-time should be a list of (HIGH LOW . IGNORED),
> as from `current-time' and `file-attributes', or nil to use the
> current time.  The obsolete form (HIGH . LOW) is also still accepted.
> The list has the following nine members: SEC is an integer between 0
> and 60; SEC is 60 for a leap second, which only some operating systems
> support.  MINUTE is an integer between 0 and 59.  HOUR is an integer
> between 0 and 23.  DAY is an integer between 1 and 31.  MONTH is an
> integer between 1 and 12.  YEAR is an integer indicating the
> four-digit year.  DOW is the day of week, an integer between 0 and 6,
> where 0 is Sunday.  DST is t if daylight saving time is in effect,
> otherwise nil.  ZONE is an integer indicating the number of seconds
> east of Greenwich.  (Note that Common Lisp has different meanings for
> DOW and ZONE.)

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner version of Vatine's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203174/lisp-decode-universal-time-is-void/4203576#4203576) is:

```
(defun day-of-week (year month day)
  "Return the day of the week given a YEAR MONTH DAY"
  (nth 6 (decode-time (encode-time 0 0 0 day month year))))
```

`decode-time` and `encode-time` are [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Conversion.html).

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found the source of this problem, but found a workaround:

```
(defun day-of-week (day month year)
  "Returns the day of the week as an integer.
Sunday is 0. Works for years after 1752."
  (let ((offset '(0 3 2 5 0 3 5 1 4 6 2 4)))
    (when (< month 3)
      (decf year 1))
    (mod
     (truncate (+ year
                  (/ year 4)
                  (/ (- year)
                     100)
                  (/ year 400)
                  (nth (1- month) offset)
                  day
                  -1))
     7)))
```